# Publishing Local DB Changes to Remote DB SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database

I have SQL Server 2012 on my local machine and I am hosting the production version of my application/database with Arvixe.

To initially set up the database on the remote server with Arvixe, I just uploaded a .bak file of my local DB. Not a big deal since it was just getting things set up, but this as you know also pushes all of my test data to the database on my production server.

My question is this .. How should I go about pushing database changes (new tables, columns, keys, etc..) from my local development environment to the production environment on Arvixe's server? A simple backup won't work now - I can't overwrite my production data and replace it with dev data.

Is there a program that I can use for this? Is there something in SQL Server 2012 that I'm just missing? All I can find is the suggestion to upload a backup version of my local DB.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to push database changes from Development to Production has little to nothing to do with where the Production instance is located.

All changes should be migrated to other environments via rollout scripts:

- You should be creating scripts for all changes as you make those changes.
- The scripts should be placed in folder for a particular release.
- The scripts should be numbered to retain the same chronological order in which those changes happened (this should eliminate -- mostly -- any dependency issues).
- The script numbering should be consistent with 2 or 3 digits for proper sorting (i.e. 01, 02, ... OR 001, 002, ...).
- The scripts should all be re-runnable (i.e. they should first check to see if the intended change has already happened and if so, skip to the next script).
- When migrating to a higher environment, just run all of the scripts.
- If any script fails, the entire process should terminate since all changes need to occur in the same order in which they happened in Development. If using **SQLCMD.EXE** to run your scripts, use the `-b` (i.e. "On error batch abort") command line switch as it will terminate the process upon any error.'
- Here is a simple CMD script (you could name it **DeploySqlScripts.cmd**) that handles one folder at a time, to a single Server/Instance, and assumes that you have a `USE [DatabaseName];` line at the top of each script:

  ```
  @ECHO OFF
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

  IF "%1"=="" (
      ECHO Usage: DeployScripts "full:\path\to\SQL\scripts" Server[\Instance]
      GOTO :EOF
  )

  FOR /F "delims=," %%B IN ('DIR /B /O:N /A-D "%1\*.sql"') DO (
      SQLCMD -b -E -S "%2" -i "%%~fB"
      IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 1 (
          ECHO. 
          ECHO     Error in release script...
          ECHO.
          EXIT /B !ERRORLEVEL!
      )
      ECHO.
  )
  ```

Also:

- If you are migrating from Dev to Prod, then you are missing at least one environment, if not 2 or even 3. You should not push changes directly from Development to Production since you might be developing things that are not ready to release. All changes that you feel are ready for release should first go to a QA environment that provides a better testing ground since it doesn't have any other changes that might invalidate certain tests.
- You really, really should have your database object CREATE scripts in some source of source code control system (a.k.a. version control system). Subversion (SVN), Git, TFS, etc. There are several options, each with their pros and cons (as well as true-believers and haters). So do some research on a few of them, pick one that suits your needs, and just use it. And yes, the release scripts should also be a part of that repository.
- There is also a tool from Redgate, [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/), that is not free, and I have not used it, but seeks to help in this area.
- For simple / small projects (single database) Microsoft has a free tool that can script out differences between a source (i.e. Development) and target (i.e. QA or Production). It is called [SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh550080.aspx) and is part of [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686.aspx).

Comment: This is all great information. I'm going to check out some things tonight. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @halterdev no problem. Please see my updated answer as I added a simple CMD script to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up triggers on the database objects you're interested in pushing and set up the production server as a linked server.
As an aside, pushing production data to the development environment is fine, but going the other way involves a lot of risk.

Comment: Right.. I would never push dev data to production. This was just for the initial setup of the DB on the production server. I will look into triggers.

Comment: The triggers will normally only fire after the table changes. However, a trick we like to use to force triggers to fire is something like `UPDATE dbo.TriggerTable SET Col1 = Col1;`